# Almacenar dato como en Preferences

Tags: android

Buenas tengo una duda (Soy nuevo en Android). Tengo 3 activity que hacen como de pantalla de bienvenida a los usuarios. ¿Hay alguna forma que cuando se pasen las 3, se almacene un Boolean, número o lo que sea para que ese usuario no vuelva a pasar por esas actividades?

Pensé algo que fuese estilo Preferences, que se almacena en la app de la persona en cuestión.

Comment: Efectivamente, puedes almacenarlo en `SharedPreferences`. Allí los datos se almacenan en pares `clave:valor`, por tanto podrías guardar tres pares así: `Activity1: true`, `Activity2: true` y `Activity3: true`  cuando se pase por cada una de ellas. Como es lógico, los valores se crearán con el valor `false` por defecto. Aunque, si no recuerdo mal, `SharedPreferences` se borra cuando el usuario limpia todos los datos de la App. Si quieres una persistencia a un nivel más alto que guarde la configuración a pesar de una limpieza general, tendrás que pensar en base de datos o en Firebase o algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes registrar los valores que determinan si la Activity fue cargada anteriormente usando los siguientes mètodos :

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void guardaValorActivity(Context context, String activity, Boolean mostrar){
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("activity_" + activity, mostrar);
    editor.commit();
}


public boolean obtieneValorActivity(Context context , String activity) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getBoolean("activity_" + activity, true);
}
```

Puedes usar el método `onCreate()` de tus Activity para determinar si fueron cargadas anteriormente, si no fueron cargadas almacena un valor boleano false, en caso de que anteriormente fueron cargadas cierra la activity mediante el mètodo `finish()` Ejemplo:

Activity 1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


   if(obtieneValorActivity(getApplicationContext(), "1")){
      guardaValorActivity(getApplicationContext(), "1", false);
   }else{
      //Cierra la Activity 1
      finish();
   }

}
```

Activity 2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


   if(obtieneValorActivity(getApplicationContext(), "2")){
      guardaValorActivity(getApplicationContext(), "2", false);
   }else{
      //Cierra la Activity 2
      finish();
   }

}
```

Activity 3

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


   if(obtieneValorActivity(getApplicationContext(), "3")){
      guardaValorActivity(getApplicationContext(), "3", false);
   }else{
      //Cierra la Activity 3
      finish();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SharedPref { // clase de preferencias
SharedPreferences mySharePref;
public static final String PREF="primeraVez";

public SharedPref(Context context){
    mySharePref = context.getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
//guarda la preferencia con : True o False
public void setNuevoState(boolean state){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharePref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(PREF, state);
    editor.commit();
}
//metodo que obtiene la preferenciaguardada
public boolean loadNuevoState(){
    boolean state = mySharePref.getBoolean(PREF, false);
    return state;
}
```

}

Comment: // en la actividad que validas
SharedPref sharedpref;

if (sharedpref.loadNuevoState()){
            //true
        } else {
            //false
        }

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es validar en el MainActivity si se ha mostrado previamente las `actividades` de Bienvenida:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Obtiene el valor de SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        Boolean isIntroComplete = pref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.preferenceString), false);

        // Valida si ya se ha mostrado la pantalla de Binevenida
        if(isIntroComplete) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Intro1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

En el caso que no se hayan mostrado las `actividades` de Bienvenida, se mostrarán y en la tercera actividad se guardará en Preference que ya se mostró la Bienvenida:

```
    public void savePreferences(View view) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.preferenceString), true);
        editor.commit();
        Intent dashboard = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(dashboard);
        finish();
    }
```

Puedes revisar el ejemplo completo lo he subido a [Github](https://github.com/israteneda/StackOverflow/tree/master/IntroPreferences).